# Order of SQL execution in BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a documentation on order of SQL execution on Big Query?
Like this : https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

Comment: Do you ask for logical or actual execution order?

Comment: @jarlh something like this: https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

Comment: Is it similar to this ? 

[https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-plan-explanation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-plan-explanation)